# ip header changing in kernel module breaks connection

Tags: linux, kernel, hook, mips32, netfilter

I have a kernel module, in which :

- It changes the saddr field of outgoing packets and fixes it back(daddr) in incomming packets ...
- I'm calculating new checksum for ip and tcp headers ...

So in client side I change ip - server side receives it(SYN packet) and sends (SYN-ACK) packet - but client side - sends (Reset) packets and trying again to process tcp handshake ...

I've seen to another kernel-module examples - dnat/snat - my code is analogical ? My be ebtables make my hooks to work incorrect ?

Interfaces:
eth0 - XXX.XXX.XXX.1
eth0:0(alias) - XXX.XXX.XXX.2

```
 /*
 Client (original ip XX.XX.XX.1)                                                                                                                         SERVER (ip YY.YY.YY.YY)
 USER-SPACE app creates tcp-socket and connects to (YY.YY.YY.YY)

  1) 
 TCP (SYN) -----------(packet ip XX.XX.XX.1-YY.YY.YY.YY[ip.sum1, tcp.sum1] )----->
 NF_INET_POST_ROUTING ( ip XX.XX.XX.2-YY.YY.YY.YY[ip.sum2, tcp.sum2] )
 =============================================================================>
 2)
 <-------TCP (SYN ACK) ------(packet ip YY.YY.YY.YY-XX.XX.XX.2[ip.sum1, tcp.sum1])
 NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING ( ip YY.YY.YY.YY-XX.XX.XX.1[ip.sum2, tcp.sum2] )
<==============================================================================


 3)

 TCP (RST) - against TCP (ACK) - that is the question ....
 =============================================================================>

  */
```

/* vars.c */

```
 struct in_addr orig_addr;
 struct in_addr virt_addr;
 pid_t pid_to_handle;


 void init_vars()
 {
      pid_to_handle = 0xAAAA;
      inet_pton(AF_INET, "XX.XX.XX.1", &orig_addr);
      inet_pton(AF_INET, "XX.XX.XX.2", &virt_addr);
 }
```

/* init.c */

```
 void register_handlers()
 {
      ...

      int ret;
      hook_out.hooknum  = NF_INET_POST_ROUTING;
      hook_out.hook     = process_out;
      hook_out.pf       = PF_INET;
      hook_out.owner    = THIS_MODULE;
      hook_out.priority = NF_IP_PRI_LAST;
      ret = nf_register_hook(&hook_out);

      hook_in.hooknum  = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;
      hook_in.hook     = process_in;
      hook_in.pf       = PF_INET;
      hook_in.owner    = THIS_MODULE;
      hook_in.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
      ret = nf_register_hook(&hook_in);
      ....

  }
```

/* out.c */

```
 unsigned int process_out(
           unsigned int hooknum,
           struct sk_buff *skb,
           const struct net_device *in,
           const struct net_device *out,
           int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
 {
      int i;
      struct iphdr *iph;
      struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
      ....

      {
           if ( skb->sk ) {
                if ( skb->sk ) {
                     struct socket * s = skb->sk->sk_socket;
                     if ( s ) {
                          struct file *f = s->file;

                          if ( f ) {
                               struct task_struct *task;
                               struct files_struct *files;

                               for_each_process(task) {
                                    if ( task->pid == pid_to_handle ) {
                                         task_lock(task);
                                         files = task->files;

                                         if ( files ) {
                                              read_lock(&files->file_lock);

                                              for ( i=0; i<1024; i++ ) {
                                                   if ( fcheck_files(files, i) == f ) {
                                                        iph->saddr = virt_addr.s_addr;
                                                        iph->check = 0;
                                                        ip_send_check (iph);

                                                        tcp_header->check = 0;
                                                        tcp_header->check = get_packet_checksum(
                                                                  iph, tcp_header, pseudogram_out, datagram_out);

                                                   }
                                              }

                                              read_unlock(&files->file_lock);
                                         }

                                         task_unlock(task);
                                    }
                               }
                          }

                     }
                }
           }
      }

      return NF_ACCEPT;
 }
```

/* in.c */

```
 unsigned int process_in(
           unsigned int hooknum,
           struct sk_buff *skb,
           const struct net_device *in,
           const struct net_device *out,
           int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
 {
      struct iphdr *iph;
      struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
      ...

      {
           if ( iphdr->daddr == virt_addr.s_addr ) {
                iphdr->daddr = orig_addr.s_addr;

                iph->check = 0;
                iph->check = ip_fast_csum(iph, iph->ihl);

                tcp_header->check = 0;
                tcp_header->check = get_packet_checksum(
                          iph, tcp_header, pseudogram_in, datagram_in);
           }
      }

      return NF_ACCEPT;
 }
```

/* utils.c */

```
 struct pseudo_header
 {
      u_int32_t source_address;
      u_int32_t dest_address;
      u_int8_t placeholder;
      u_int8_t protocol;
      u_int16_t tcp_length;
 };

 /*
      Generic checksum calculation function
 */
 unsigned short csum(unsigned short *ptr,int nbytes) {
      register long sum;
      unsigned short oddbyte;
      register short answer;

      sum = 0;
      while (nbytes > 1) {
           sum += *ptr++;
           nbytes -= 2;
      }
      if (nbytes == 1) {
           oddbyte = 0;
           *((u_char * ) & oddbyte) = *(u_char *) ptr;
           sum += oddbyte;
      }

      sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
      sum = sum + (sum >> 16);
      answer = (short) ~sum;

      return (answer);

 }

 static char *pseudogram_out = NULL;
 static char *datagram_out = NULL;
 static char *pseudogram_in = NULL;
 static char *datagram_in = NULL;


 int get_packet_checksum(struct iphdr *ip_header, struct tcphdr *tcp_header, char *pseudogram, char *datagram)
 {
      if ( (pseudogram == NULL) || (datagram == NULL) )
           return -1;

      char source_ip[32] , *data;
      memset (datagram, 0, 4096);
      memset (pseudogram, 0, 4096);
      memcpy(datagram, ip_header, ip_header->tot_len);
      ip_header = (struct iphdr *)datagram;
      tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)(datagram + sizeof(struct iphdr));

      struct sockaddr_in sin;
      struct pseudo_header psh;
      size_t tcp_data_len = ip_header->tot_len - sizeof(struct iphdr) - sizeof(struct tcphdr);

      psh.source_address = ip_header->saddr;
      psh.dest_address = ip_header->daddr;
      psh.placeholder = 0;
      psh.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
      psh.tcp_length = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr) + tcp_data_len );

      int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + tcp_data_len;
      memcpy(pseudogram , (char*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
      memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) , tcp_header , sizeof(struct tcphdr) + tcp_data_len);

      return csum((unsigned short*)pseudogram, psize);
 }
```

tcpump log on server:

```
11:27:03.164239 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 48, id 61125, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782 > YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999: Flags [S], cksum 0xa1cb (correct), seq 492452010, win 5840, options [mss 1448,sackOK,TS val 251503 ecr 0,nop,wscale 1], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c eec5 4000 3006 a014 xxxx xxx2  E..<..@.0....5}.
    0x0010:  yyyy yyyy 83f6 2327 1d5a 38aa 0000 0000  .E....#'.Z8.....
    0x0020:  a002 16d0 a1cb 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ................
    0x0030:  0003 d66f 0000 0000 0103 0301            ...o........
11:27:03.164394 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbc10 (incorrect -> 0x597a), seq 1446351294, ack 492452011, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 842060729 ecr 251503,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 7eda yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.@.~..E..
    0x0010:  xxxx xxx2 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .5}.#'..V5...Z8.
    0x0020:  a012 7120 bc10 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..q.............
    0x0030:  3230 d3b9 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
11:27:04.181972 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbc10 (incorrect -> 0x587b), seq 1446351294, ack 492452011, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 842060984 ecr 251503,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 7eda yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.@.~..E..
    0x0010:  xxxx xxx2 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .5}.#'..V5...Z8.
    0x0020:  a012 7120 bc10 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..q.............
    0x0030:  3230 d4b8 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
11:27:05.525221 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 48, id 61126, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782 > YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999: Flags [S], cksum 0x9612 (correct), seq 492452010, win 5840, options [mss 1448,sackOK,TS val 254504 ecr 0,nop,wscale 1], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c eec6 4000 3006 a013 xxxx xxx2  E..<..@.0....5}.
    0x0010:  yyyy yyyy 83f6 2327 1d5a 38aa 0000 0000  .E....#'.Z8.....
    0x0020:  a002 16d0 9612 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ................
    0x0030:  0003 e228 0000 0000 0103 0301            ...(........
11:27:05.525319 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbc10 (incorrect -> 0x572c), seq 1446351294, ack 492452011, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 842061319 ecr 251503,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 7eda yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.@.~..E..
    0x0010:  xxxx xxx2 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .5}.#'..V5...Z8.
    0x0020:  a012 7120 bc10 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..q.............
    0x0030:  3230 d607 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
11:27:07.541981 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbc10 (incorrect -> 0x5533), seq 1446351294, ack 492452011, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 842061824 ecr 251503,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 7eda yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.@.~..E..
    0x0010:  xxxx xxx2 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .5}.#'..V5...Z8.
    0x0020:  a012 7120 bc10 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..q.............
    0x0030:  3230 d800 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
11:27:11.524252 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 48, id 61127, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782 > YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999: Flags [S], cksum 0x7ea2 (correct), seq 492452010, win 5840, options [mss 1448,sackOK,TS val 260504 ecr 0,nop,wscale 1], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c eec7 4000 3006 a012 xxxx xxx2  E..<..@.0....5}.
    0x0010:  yyyy yyyy 83f6 2327 1d5a 38aa 0000 0000  .E....#'.Z8.....
    0x0020:  a002 16d0 7ea2 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ....~...........
    0x0030:  0003 f998 0000 0000 0103 0301            ............
11:27:11.524331 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > XXX.XXX.XXX.x2.33782: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbc10 (incorrect -> 0x5150), seq 1446351294, ack 492452011, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 842062819 ecr 251503,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 4006 7eda yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.@.~..E..
    0x0010:  xxxx xxx2 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .5}.#'..V5...Z8.
    0x0020:  a012 7120 bc10 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ..q.............
    0x0030:  3230 dbe3 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
```

tcpdump on client:

```
     06:27:02.370828 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61125, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60) xxx.xxx.xxx.X2.33782 > YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999: S, cksum 0xa1bf (correct), 492452010:492452010(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 251503 0,nop,wscale 1>
      0x0000:  4500 003c eec5 4000 4006 9014 xxxx xxx2  E..<..@.@....5}.
      0x0010:  yyyy yyyy 83f6 2327 1d5a 38aa 0000 0000  .E....#'.Z8.....
      0x0020:  a002 16d0 a1bf 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ................
      0x0030:  0003 d66f 0000 0000 0103 0301            ...o........
 06:27:03.301644 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60, bad cksum 89d9 (->89da)!) YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > xxx.xxx.xxx.x1.33782: S, cksum 0x5986 (correct), 1446351294:1446351294(0) ack 492452011 win 28960 <mss 1448,sackOK,timestamp 842060729 251503,nop,wscale 7>
      0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3506 89d9 yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.5....E..
      0x0010:  xxxx xxx1 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .4}.#'..V5...Z8.
      0x0020:  a012 7120 5986 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ..q.Y...........
      0x0030:  3230 d3b9 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
 06:27:04.318359 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60, bad cksum 89d9 (->89da)!) YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > xxx.xxx.xxx.x1.33782: S, cksum 0x5887 (correct), 1446351294:1446351294(0) ack 492452011 win 28960 <mss 1448,sackOK,timestamp 842060984 251503,nop,wscale 7>
      0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3506 89d9 yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.5....E..
      0x0010:  xxxx xxx1 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .4}.#'..V5...Z8.
      0x0020:  a012 7120 5887 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ..q.X...........
      0x0030:  3230 d4b8 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
 06:27:05.371079 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61126, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60) xxx.xxx.xxx.X2.33782 > YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999: S, cksum 0x9606 (correct), 492452010:492452010(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 254504 0,nop,wscale 1>
      0x0000:  4500 003c eec6 4000 4006 9013 xxxx xxx2  E..<..@.@....5}.
      0x0010:  yyyy yyyy 83f6 2327 1d5a 38aa 0000 0000  .E....#'.Z8.....
      0x0020:  a002 16d0 9606 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ................
      0x0030:  0003 e228 0000 0000 0103 0301            ...(........
 06:27:05.661863 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60, bad cksum 89d9 (->89da)!) YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > xxx.xxx.xxx.x1.33782: S, cksum 0x5738 (correct), 1446351294:1446351294(0) ack 492452011 win 28960 <mss 1448,sackOK,timestamp 842061319 251503,nop,wscale 7>
      0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3506 89d9 yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.5....E..
      0x0010:  xxxx xxx1 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .4}.#'..V5...Z8.
      0x0020:  a012 7120 5738 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ..q.W8..........
      0x0030:  3230 d607 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
 06:27:07.677895 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60, bad cksum 89d9 (->89da)!) YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > xxx.xxx.xxx.x1.33782: S, cksum 0x553f (correct), 1446351294:1446351294(0) ack 492452011 win 28960 <mss 1448,sackOK,timestamp 842061824 251503,nop,wscale 7>
      0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3506 89d9 yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.5....E..
      0x0010:  xxxx xxx1 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .4}.#'..V5...Z8.
      0x0020:  a012 7120 553f 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ..q.U?..........
      0x0030:  3230 d800 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
 06:27:11.371065 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61127, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60) xxx.xxx.xxx.X2.33782 > YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999: S, cksum 0x7e96 (correct), 492452010:492452010(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 260504 0,nop,wscale 1>
      0x0000:  4500 003c eec7 4000 4006 9012 xxxx xxx2  E..<..@.@....5}.
      0x0010:  yyyy yyyy 83f6 2327 1d5a 38aa 0000 0000  .E....#'.Z8.....
      0x0020:  a002 16d0 7e96 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ....~...........
      0x0030:  0003 f998 0000 0000 0103 0301            ............
 06:27:11.660592 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60, bad cksum 89d9 (->89da)!) YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > xxx.xxx.xxx.x1.33782: S, cksum 0x515c (correct), 1446351294:1446351294(0) ack 492452011 win 28960 <mss 1448,sackOK,timestamp 842062819 251503,nop,wscale 7>
      0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3506 89d9 yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.5....E..
      0x0010:  xxxx xxx1 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .4}.#'..V5...Z8.
      0x0020:  a012 7120 515c 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ..q.Q\..........
      0x0030:  3230 dbe3 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
 06:27:15.870063 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60, bad cksum 89d9 (->89da)!) YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > xxx.xxx.xxx.x1.33782: S, cksum 0x4d3f (correct), 1446351294:1446351294(0) ack 492452011 win 28960 <mss 1448,sackOK,timestamp 842063872 251503,nop,wscale 7>
      0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3506 89d9 yyyy yyyy  E..<..@.5....E..
      0x0010:  xxxx xxx1 2327 83f6 5635 91be 1d5a 38ab  .4}.#'..V5...Z8.
      0x0020:  a012 7120 4d3f 0000 0204 05a8 0402 080a  ..q.M?..........
      0x0030:  3230 e000 0003 d66f 0103 0307            20.....o....
 06:27:24.062254 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 53, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60, bad cksum 89d9 (->89da)!) YYY.YY.YYY.YYY.8999 > xxx.xxx.xxx.x1.33782: S, cksum 0x453f (correct), 1446351294:1446351294(0) ack 492452011
```

Comment: Are you modifying the IP stack or just modifying the headers yourself?  If you're tinkering with the headers, of course the real IP stack will send RST packets back; it has no knowledge of the packets.

Comment: I'm only modifiing headers .... what I need to make IP stack not to drop incoming packets ???

Comment: Use the IP stack.  Alternatively... I'll post an answer.

Comment: AFAIK this should work fine with the correct netfilter hooks. Can you use tcpdump/wireshark on the client machine to see the packet it receives? Also, post your code/pseudo-code.

Comment: @YSK I cannot paste code snippets that's why here are the links... : kernel module snippets: [https://pastebin.com/hJQ91uje] client-side tcpdump: [https://pastebin.com/1rWEMj4T] server-side tcpdump: [https://pastebin.com/C4gDukLD] XXX.XXX.XXX.1 - eth0 interface IP XXX.XXX.XXX.2 - eth0:0 alias IP YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY - server IP

Comment: Links are empty...

Comment: @YSK - Sorry. I've updated guestion....

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, it sounds like the problem is that you are modifying aspects of the packet outside of the TCP/IP stack.  This creates a situation where the returning SYN/ACK, for example, will not be associated with any connection that the TCP/IP stack is aware of, so it will react by resetting the connection.

A quick and dirty way around this is to use the IPTables firewall to prevent the system from being able to send RST packets outbound.  Of course, this means that your packet-tinkering will also be prevented from sending outbound RST packets.

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP`

Comment: may be I've explained not fully, in this question I've mode simple scheme of my problem ....  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302523/ip-header-changing-in-kernel-module-breaks-connection-rst-against-ack - I dont create raw packets - but modifiing that, which were created by user space application .... and some socket structure is assosiated with them in kernel space ....

Comment: If you modify them after they leave the TCP/IP stack, the stack won't recognize the returning ACKs.